# Is (long long)x same as (long long)floor(x) in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, rounding

Suppose I have a double data type, variable named 'x'.Is it necessary that casting the double to long long data type gives same result as casting to long long floor(x).

Comment: Why the downvotes? Can this question be improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not the same.

The cast truncates (rounds toward zero), the `floor` function rounds down.

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/k8JuA9

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double x = -1.4;
    std::cout << "(long long)x        = " << ((long long)x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "(long long)floor(x) = " << ((long long)floor(x)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```